# React - Complex object state not updating the Textbox value on change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have used a complex object to store the state. Each of it's property is attached to a set of checkboxes and textbox. When the checkbox is checked or unchecked the state is updated as expected, however in case of textbox. When I type something it doesn't update the value. Using console, I could see the state object is updated however the value is not refeclted on the textbox. I think I am missing something here. Below is the react component code.

```
const JsonSchemaGenerator = (props) => {
    const [schemaOptions, setSchemaOptions] = useState({
    requireId: true,
    requireRequired: true,
    requireDefault: true,
    requireExample: true,
    requireTitle: true,
    topexamples: 1
});

    const toogleChange = (event) => {
        let newSchemaOptions = schemaOptions;
      console.log(event.target.type);
        if(event.target.type==='checkbox'){
         newSchemaOptions[event.target.name]=!schemaOptions[event.target.name];
        }
      else if(event.target.type==='text'){
        newSchemaOptions[event.target.name]=event.target.value;
      }
        setSchemaOptions(newSchemaOptions);
      console.log(newSchemaOptions);
      console.log(schemaOptions);
    }

    return (
        <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="requireId" defaultChecked={schemaOptions.requireId} onChange={toogleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="SId">Include Id?</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="requireTitle" defaultChecked={schemaOptions.requireTitle} onChange={toogleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="STitle">Include Title?</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="requireRequired" defaultChecked={schemaOptions.requireRequired} onChange={toogleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="SRequired">Include Required?</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="requireDefault" defaultChecked={schemaOptions.requireDefault} onChange={toogleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="SDefault">Include Default?</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="requireExample" defaultChecked={schemaOptions.requireExample} onChange={toogleChange} />
                    <label htmlFor="SExample">Include Example?</label>&nbsp;Top <input type="text" name="topexamples" value={schemaOptions.topexamples} onChange={toogleChange} /> examples.
                </div>
            </div>
    );
}
```

Below is the JSComplete Code ready for execution
https://jscomplete.com/playground/s945041

Comment: The issue you're facing is related to how you're updating the state in React. React's state updates are asynchronous, and the state object is immutable. When you do:

`let newSchemaOptions = schemaOptions;`
You're not actually creating a new object; you're creating a new reference to the existing object. Therefore, when you modify newSchemaOptions, you're directly modifying the existing state, which is not the correct way to handle state in React.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for sure Jimmy's comment helped to get to the solution. Immutable object is causing this issue. I could easily fix this issue as below. Hope this  might help someone like me :P

```
const toogleChange = (event) => {
  // Constructing a new object using the properties of existing object
    let newSchemaOptions = {...schemaOptions};
    if(event.target.type==='checkbox'){
     newSchemaOptions[event.target.name]=!schemaOptions[event.target.name];
    }
  else if(event.target.type==='text'){
    newSchemaOptions[event.target.name]=event.target.value;
  }
    setSchemaOptions(newSchemaOptions);
}
```